# How can I identify a user agent from the numeric code that Salesforce exposes in the Event Log

Tags: eventlogfile

The Event Log API CSV exposes a USER_AGENT column. The [API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#rest-api) for this column states:

> **USER_AGENT**
>   *Type:* Number
>   *Description:* The numeric code for the type of client used to make the request (for example, the browser, application, or API).

How can I decode what this numeric value represents?

[image]

Some example values used against the REST API are `9999` and `13047000`.

Ideally I'd like to be able to work back to, for example, the [User agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) that a browser sent with the request.

My ultimate goal is to send in custom user agent strings and then identify them in the resulting numeric codes.

Answer (score 3):

Via [Adam Torman](https://twitter.com/atorman/status/684870475663593472) - [Browser and User Agent Values](http://www.salesforcehacker.com/2015/02/browser-and-user-agent-values.html)

> User agent versions are calculated dynamically:
>
> 1. The first two digits are reserved for browser family/name.
> 2. The next three digits are for major version numbers, such as "008" for version 8.
> 3. The last three digits are flags for describing browser variants.
>
>    a. The first two digits can be used as desired internally and may differ from browser to browser. Commonly these would be used for minor versions or for things like compatibility view mode flags.
>
>    b. The last digit indicates device type.

```
0 = desktop/laptop
1 = mobile (generic/any/unknown)
2 = phone
3 = tablet
4 = media player
5 = reserved
6-9 = vary by UserAgent
```

> Examples:

```
Value    - Label output
10007000 - IE 7
10008000 - IE 8
11015000 - FF 15
12024000 - Chrome 24
12024001 - Mobile Chrome 24
```

So `13047000` from the example in the question is Chrome 47 Desktop/Laptop

`9999` is [most likely](https://twitter.com/atorman/status/685000718848163840) an "unknown" user agent string. There is talk of a [pilot program to support unknown user agent strings](https://twitter.com/atorman/status/685000884007256065).